# How to load external Cordova url in Android WebView?

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

The url loads without any issue in Google Chrome. I have tried CordovaWebView but I am getting error with thread. How do I load the url as Google Chrome loads it?

update:
I have added the config.xml and configured with the right url

Comment: What is the error? / What is in the logcat?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.execute(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to declare the thread pool as follows:

```
private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

Then return `threadPool` in `getThreadPool()` method.

source: http://infil00p.org/android/cordova/phonegap/2012/12/04/advanced-tutorial-using-cordovawebview-on-android/